# Windows Phone Power Tools not showing proper emulator?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am installing windows phone power tools. 
I am getting emulators like emulator Windows Phone7.5, like that. 
But i need a windows emulator like Emulator WXGA. 
Please help me for this.

Comment: What tools have you installed ? and from where ?

Comment: WPSDKv71_en1,WP7.8 SDK Update,WindowsPlatformLoggerSetup,Win 8 SDK..these are the tools i have installed

Comment: in control panel it is showing..windowsphonesdk7.1-ENU,windowsphonesdk7.1Add-in for visualstudio2010,windowsphonesdk8.0-ENU,windowsphonesdk8.0-ENU,WCFDataservicesSDK for windows phone,windows platform logger setup,WPFtoolkitfebruary2010(version3.5),please help me for installing windows phone power tools

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you un-install the SDKs, and then get the SDK for WP8 from the [official site](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471).

It has the WP7.5 support there as well, thus should work for both development purposes. Also do remember to check the [Windows Phone Emulator for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402563%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), do note the requirements for SLAT, DEP & that you need to have Windows 8 Pro or Enterprise 64 bit Operating System for the Hyper V to be present in there as well.

Comment: hi,I uninstalled every thing but when iam installing WPExpressfull iam getting error like unable to install package resources